# R: Ranking Tied Groups of Data

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
df= data.frame(
person = c("person0", "person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", "person5", "person6"),
var1 = c(11,10,5,2,1,0,0),
var2 = c(11, 5, 10, 2,1,1,0),
var3 = c(11, 10, 10, 2,0,1,0)
)


   person var1 var2 var3
1 person0   11   11   11
2 person1   10    5   10
3 person2    5   10   10
4 person3    2    2    2
5 person4    1    1    0
6 person5    0    1    1
7 person6    0    0    0
```

In the above data:

- Person0 has higher values of var1,var2,var3 compared to everyone else
- Person1 and Person2 have higher values of var1,var2,var3 compared to everyone except Person0 ... but amongst themselves are not strictly higher than each other
- etc.

**My Question:** Is it possible to somehow identify within this data to find out which groups of people are tied amongst themselves ... and rank them relative to others?

For example, Person4 and Person5 are tied amongst themselves, larger than Person6 but smaller than all other Persons.

Is it somehow possible to do this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rank` to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
person = c("person0", "person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", "person5", "person6"),
var1 = c(11,10,5,2,1,0,0),
var2 = c(11, 5, 10, 2,1,1,0),
var3 = c(11, 10, 10, 2,0,1,0)
)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., -person))) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(df2$total, ties.method = "max"))%>%
  arrange(rank)
```

Here we have calculated a total score for each person using `rowSums`. We get rid of the person column because it is not numeric data.

Then we use `rank` based on their total to give each person a ranking. You can change the way ties are ranked by changing the argument in the `ties.method` if you like.